# Sort multigigabyte xml file

Tags: xml, sorting

How to sort all tags in multigigabyte xml file alphabetically, all equal tags should also be sorted by attributes?
All methods suggested in related questions fail for such large data.

I'm looking for existing tools for Windows or Linux.

Comment: Do you have access to a database server that you could import the XML into?  Such a verbose data exchange format is probably bad for such a large amount of data.

Comment: Define: "*sort all elements*" in an XML file.

Comment: Maybe divide it into chucks, sort elements inside them, and then merge the chunks back into one huge xml document?

Comment: Best? For what? Speed? Memory consumption? Something else? Also - what language and platform are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the original goal was to be able to compare to extremely large xmls which contained similar data but in different order I ended up doing splitting xmls in logical chunks (each xml contained thousands of processed documents, and it was split so each document went into separate file with csplit utility), and then compared each pair of equally size documents from two xmls (luckily there were no equally sized documents within one xml).

Not perfect solution but it worked withing reasonable time and space constraints

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an XSLT to do the sorting, you can use the **streaming-safe subset** of XSLT with a streaming-enabled processor like Saxon. Saxon in streaming mode can easily manage gigabytes of input XML data.

The Saxon website has very detailed documentation about [streaming XSLT templates](http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/sourcedocs/streaming/streaming-templates.xml).

Comment: I didn't yet use XLST to do the sorting. Could you point to any walk through to start with?

Comment: Kay's blog contains many useful resources: http://saxonica.blogharbor.com/blog?cmd=search&keywords=streaming

Comment: Seems like this won't help - looking into the article you've provided in original response - **Sorting (xsl:sort), grouping (xsl:for-each-group), and numbering (xsl:number) are not supported in streaming mode**