# Sorting BIG Data XML file

Tags: java, xml, bigdata

I have an XML file that has a compressed size of about 100 GB (uncompressed 1 TB). This file contains about 100 million entries in the following way:

```
<root>
  <entry>
    <id>1234</id>
     ...
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <id>1230</id>
    ...
  </entry
</root>
```

I would like to sort this file by id. What would be a good way to do so?

By the way, I can use a machine with 16 cores and 128 GB RAM.

Comment: A good way would be to avoid sorting it, why do you need to sort it?

Comment: I'm sorry, this is confidential information. But I really need this file sorted for another big data application.

Comment: How many entries do you have approximatively? How big is an entry?

Comment: I don't think you should have it processed as is in a single large file. YOu should split it up into chucks and process one chunk at a time.

Comment: I have about 100 million entries and on average one entry is about 10,000 Bytes (uncompressed).

Comment: that is fine, but can you split it up into, maybe, 10000 entries per file?

Comment: An alternative idea: Hold all data compressed in memory. Do you have any advice on an appropriate compression algorithm/library suitable for this?

Comment: 128 RAM? Is that gigabytes?

Comment: Yes, it's 128 GB RAM. I updated the question.

Comment: if entries are not recursive then this is pretty simple, simply store each entry into separate file and sort only references to file + id and then write then to the new document...

Answer (score 0):

You can think about using a streaming processor like Saxon http://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation/sourcedocs/streaming/ and sort using XSLT.

Another option may be to store the data as key, values in DB, order them using SQL and recreating the XML. You would be leveraging the power of DB to manage large amount of data.

Similar question (not same): [Sort multigigabyte xml file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9095653/sort-multigigabyte-xml-file)

Comment: How does Saxon and XSLT cope with files which do not fit in main memory?

Comment: I think a DB is not appropriate as IO operations to disk are really slow (only about 100 per second).

Comment: @David your data cannot fit into your memory so you don't have really the choice, you need to persist your transformation somehow and a database seems to be a good choice in your case. A NoSQL database like mongodb

Comment: Maybe I should be a bit more precise: I do not mind writing large amounts to disk sequentially. However, I do mind random IO operations.

Answer (score 0):

Because the values (i.e *id*) are **natural numbers**, the best algorithm to sort them is ***Counting Sort*** with **TETA(n)** time order.

Suppose the values are in range [1 .. k]

> Counting Sort >

Temp: **C[1..k]**

Input:  **A[1..n]**

Output: **B[1..n]**

```
CountingSort (A, B, k)
{
   for(i=1 to k) C[i]=0;
   for(i=1 to n) C[A[i]]++;
   for(i=2 to k) C[i]=C[i]+C[i-1];
   for(i=n downto 1)
   {
      B[C[A[i]]] = A[i];
      C[A[i]]--;
   }
}
```

This algorithm is *Stable*.

> You can also use **Radix Sort** with the same order.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I thought about something similar: Split the large file into many smaller files using counting sort/bins, sort each file individually, and merge all files in the end.

Do you have any thoughts/advice on this?

Comment: It's a good idea. 1. Split the file into smaller files which fit in main memory. 2. Sort each new file using Counting Sort or Radix Sort 3. Mege all files in a single file.

Answer (score 0):

At this stage it's useful to remember the techniques that people used to sort magnetic tapes or decks of punched cards, in the days when the data was much larger than available direct access memory. (I once watched a team of operators sort a quarter of a million cards - about 120 trays). You basically need a combination of streaming, merging, and splitting, which are all operations available in principle using XSLT 3.0. There are two processors available, Saxon-EE and Exselt, and neither is yet a 100% complete implementation, so you'll be constrained by the limitations of the products more than the spec.

My instinct would be to go for a digit-by-digit sort. You don't say how long the id's used as sort keys are. "Digits" here of course doesn't have to mean decimal digits, but assuming decimal for simplicity, the basic idea is that you first split the file into 10 buckets based on the last digit of the sort key, then you process the buckets in sequence based on this ordering, this time sorting by the penultimate digit, and carry on for as many digits as there are in the key: one pass of the complete file for each digit in the sort key.

If the id's are dense then presumably with 100m keys they are about 8 digits long, that would be 8 passes and if we assume a processing speed of 10Gb/min, which is probably the best you can get from off-the-shelf XML parsers, then each pass of a 1Tb file is going to take 2 hours, so 8 passes would be 16 hours. But it might be better to use say base-100 so you split into 100 files on each pass, then you only have 4 passes.

The essential XSLT 3.0 code is:

```
<xsl:stream href="in.xml">
 <xsl:fork>
  <xsl:for-each-group select="record" 
       group-by="substring(key, $digit, 1)">
   <xsl:result-document href="temp{current-grouping-key()}">
     <xsl:sequence select="current-group()"/>
   </xsl:result-document>
 </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:fork>
```

Now the bad news: in Saxon-EE 9.7 this code probably isn't sufficiently optimised. Although in principle the items in each group could be streamed directly to the relevant serialised result-document, Saxon doesn't yet treat this case specially and will build each group in memory before processing it. I don't know if Exselt can do any better.

So is there an alternative? Well, perhaps we could try something like this:

1. Split the file into N files: that is, put the first X/N items into file 1, the next X/N into file 2, and so on.
2. Sort each file, conventionally in memory.
3. Do a streamed merge of the resulting files, using xsl:merge.

I think that would work in Saxon. The first step can be done using `<xsl:for-each-group group-adjacent="(position()-1) idiv $N">` which is fully streamed in Saxon.

This is essentially a 3-pass solution, in that each item is parsed and serialized three times. I would go for splitting the 1Tb file into 100 10Gb files. Doing an in-memory XSLT sort of a 10Gb is pushing it, but you've got some horsepower to play with. You could however run into Java addressing limits: arrays and strings have 1G limits, I think.